# Linking features via correlations

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, association-measure, compositional-data

I am comparing two tables with different size of features (rows), but the same number of samples (columns). I know that a significant part of the features are the same in the two tables, but they are labeled by different names, and I am trying to restore the link by correlating them. The current procedure is as follows:

- correlate a row of table 1 with a row of table two (Pearson correlation)
- if the correlation coefficient is above certain threshold, the two features are identical.

There are some issues here:

- Spurious correlations: some rows contain many zeros, so the correlation may be good, but needs to be adjusted for the number of non-zero entries
- occasionally there are ambiguities (above the threshold correlation with more than one feature from another table)

Perhaps this is a standard statistical problem, and I would appreciate tips on where to look, how it is usually done or what are the good practices.

In case it helps: the data are compositional (i.e., the columns sum to 1), but there are many zeros.

**Update**
To try to set it in a more formal way for just two features:

- $\{(x_i,y_i)|i=1..n\}$ are paired data
- every data point is generated from probability density $f(x_i|\theta_i)f(y_i|\eta_i)$ (that is, the probability law for $x_i$ and $y_i$ is the same).
- I need to test whether $\vec{\theta}$ and $\vec{\eta}$ are proportional to each other or not.

Comment: Samples are in rows, features/variables are in columns. Basically you have the same variables in two different data sets, but you cannot identify and match them because they have different names. And you want to use correlation to match variables from set 1 to variables from set 2. There is no standard approach for this because this is not a standard problem.

Comment: @user2974951 Sorry, I know what I described is inverse of the convention traditional in statistics - I just hoped to make less errors by keeping it as it is. The features are not exactly the same, but they come from two overlapping sets.

Comment: Since the data are paired, why would the values of one feature in one dataset differ at all from the values in the other dataset?  Nothing in your statement of the problem corresponds to comparing proportions of *parameters* in two models, making it completely unclear what your $\theta_i$ and $\eta_i$ might mean.

Comment: @whuber Because the number of features in the two tables is normalized (the sum is zero). The two tables arise from treating the same data with different software, which may map part of the data on wrong features or features without correspondence in the other dataset. Also, some of the data might remain unmapped.

Comment: I don't think your update is helpful; it would be better to just show some actual data.